# Brute-force vertex enumeration for polytope

Tags: convex-analysis, polytopes, convex-hulls

Let $P$ be a polytope of $\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by a (bounded) finite family of half-spaces $t_i \cdot x \leq q_i$ with every $t_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$ non-zero and $q \in \mathbb{R}$. There is no assumption on $P$ being full-dimensional or that the family of half-spaces is irredundant.

Consider every intersection of bounding hyperplanes of these half-spaces, for which the intersection has dimension zero, i.e. is a single point. Discard every such singleton that is not contained in $P$.

Does the resulting singletons constitute precisely the vertices of $P$?

Comment: My immediate reaction is *Yes*, this should work.